# Combinatorics Question - Boys selecting candies from a bowl

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, combinations

I'm seeking help with solving this problem.

> There are two boys: Mike and Dan. There is a lady with a bowl containing $7$ different candies (e.g: M&M, Kitkat, etc.). The lady tells the boys that they can each take two candies from the bowl. If Mike picks first, how many ways are there for them to select their  candies?

I thought that the result might be $\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}$, but I'm not sure about it. Would like to get help to understand if my intuition is correct.

Explanation: Mike picks first, choosing combinations of $2$ elements from a $7$-element set. Dan picks second, choosing combinations of $2$ elements from a $5$-element set.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Sorry about it, added my attempt.

Comment: You are right...

Comment: If the question demands that each boy chooses both his candies simultaneously, then the answer is correct. If, perhaps the question is a bit complex, it may be required to see the following orders of selection: M chooses 1, then D chooses 1, M, then finally D. Or, maybe, M,D,D,M. Get what I mean? (M stands for Mike, D for Dan). But, I don't the question demands that, so... You're right!

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right.

Mike can pick two candies from a bowl with seven candies in $C_7^2$ different ways. After that there will be five candies left. Then Dan choses two candies from the remaining five and that can be done in $C_5^2$ ways. Thus the answer is $C_7^2 C_5^2 = 420$.